# Monitoring GDI calls

Tags: windows, monitoring, gdi

Is there a tool that allows one to monitor GDI calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools like [AutomatedQA AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/index.asp) can help you diagnose GDI usage. A much simpler, but free tool one can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188782.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Good advice, Lars. I've had a similar problem. Now use deleaker and do not worry;) GDI do not lose!